# how to save json array in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

i tried creating a new mongodb document using nodejs here is my schema

```
var resumeSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{   
    user:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    education:[
        {
            name:{type: String, required: true},
            qualification:{type: String, required: true},
            startEnd:{type: String, required: true},
            note:{type: String, required: true}
        }
    ],
    experience:[
        {
            employer:{type: String, required: true},
            jobTitle:{type: String, required: true},
            startEnd:{type: String, required: true},
            note:{type: String, required: true}
        }
    ]
 }
)
var Resume = mongoose.model('Resume', resumeSchema);
```

here is my nodejs route

```
router.post('/add-resume', function(req, res, next) {
     var newResume = new Resume();
        newResume.user = req.user._id;
        newResume.education= req.body.educations;
        newResume.experience = req.body.experiences;

      newResume.save(function(err, resume){
          if (err) { 
            return next(err); 
          }else{
             console.log(resume);
        }
    });
 });
});
```

Where req.body.educations and req.body.experiences are json array.

please i need help on how to fix this

am using angular js on the client side and the data am sending to the server is a formData. here is my client code

```
 angular
.module('app')
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
          var modelSetter = model.assign;
          element.bind('change', function(){
             scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
             });
          });
       }
    };
 }]);

 angular
 .module('app')
 .controller('addresumeCtrl', addresumeCtrl);

 function addresumeCtrl ($scope,ngDialog,$http) {

 $scope.resume = {};
 $scope.educations = [];
 $scope.experiences = [];

 $scope.resume.educations = $scope.educations;
 $scope.resume.experiences = $scope.experiences;
 $scope.addNewEducation = function() {
    $scope.educations.push({});
 };

$scope.addNewExperience = function() {
   $scope.experiences.push({});
};

$scope.removeEducation = function(index) {
  $scope.educations.splice(index, 1);
};

$scope.removeExperience = function(index) {
  $scope.experiences.splice(index, 1);
};

$scope.create = function(){
 var uploadUrl = "/user/add-resume";
 var fd = new FormData();
 for(var key in $scope.resume)
    fd.append(key, $scope.resume[key]);
 $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
  }).then(function (response) {

 }, function (error) {

});
```

};

}

and here is the html

```
 <form>

  <!-- Education -->
  <div class="form with-line">
    <h5>Education <span>(optional)</span></h5>
    <div class="form-inside">

      <!-- Add Education -->
      <div data-ng-repeat="education in educations" class="form boxed education-box">
        <a href="" ng-click="removeEducation(educations.indexOf(education))" class="close-form  button"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
        <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="School Name" ng-model="education.name"/>
        <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Qualification(s)" ng-model="education.qualification"/>
        <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Start - end date eg 2000 - 2010" ng-model="education.startEnd"/>
        <textarea name="desc" id="desc" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Notes (optional)" ng-model="education.note" ></textarea>
      </div>

      <a href="" class="button gray" ng-click="addNewEducation()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Education</a>

    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Experience  -->
  <div class="form with-line">
    <h5>Experience <span>(optional)</span></h5>
    <div class="form-inside">

      <!-- Add Experience -->
      <div data-ng-repeat="experience in experiences" class="form boxed experience-box">
        <a href="" ng-click="removeExperience(experiences.indexOf(experience))"  class="close-form button"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
        <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Employer" ng-model="experience.employer"/>
        <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Job Title" ng-model="experience.jobTitle"/>
        <input class="search-field" type="text" placeholder="Start / end date eg 2000 - 2010" ng-model="experience.startEnd"/>
        <textarea name="desc1" id="desc1" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Notes (optional)" ng-model="experience.note"></textarea>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="button gray"  ng-click="addNewExperience()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Experience</a>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="divider margin-top-0 padding-reset"></div>
  <a href="" ng-click="create()" class="button big margin-top-5">Preview <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show the `req.body.educations` and `req.body.experiences` content?

Comment: think i have a problem with the client side

Comment: I have just added the client side (angular.js).